# TestNG script not able to open Excel when run from .bat file

Tags: excel, batch-file, testng

My TestNg script uses input data from Excel using DataProvider. It works fine when I run the `testng.xml` file from Eclipse. 
But it is not working when I try to run the same from .bat file. It fails at the point where trying to open the Excel file.
Please help.

This is my DataProvider class:

```
@DataProvider(name="DataProvider")
public static Object[][] passExcelData(Method m) throws BiffException,   IOException
{
    String sheetName = m.getName();
    config = new ExcelDataConfig("inputData.xlsx", sheetName);
    int rows = config.getRowCount(sheetName);
    int cols = config.getColCount(sheetName);
    Object[][] data = new Object[rows][cols];

    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<cols; j++)
        {
            data[i][j] = config.getData(sheetName, i, j);
        }
    }
    return data;
  }
```

And below is the BeforeClass and test calling DataProvider:

```
@BeforeClass
public void setup() throws InterruptedException
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", rootFolder +"Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    System.out.println("setup done");
}

@Test(priority = 7, dataProvider="DataProvider")
public void EmailAlerts(String Product, String URL, String username, String password) throws InterruptedException
{   
    functionName = Product + "_EmailAlerts_" +username;
    HomePage(URL);
    Login.loginProcess(username, password);
    EmailAlerts.EmailAlerts_Process();
    Logout();
}
```

It doesn't through any error as such. BeforeClass runs without issues. It opens the browser and displays "Setup done" message. It even calls DataProvider class, but not able to open excel file. 
This problem is happening only when I run from .bat file. If I cut out reading from excel part and hard code the input data in DataProvider class - the same bat file works fine.

---

I have simplified my script and set Verbose to 10. Below is the latest:

```
public class Master {
@Test
public void sample() throws Exception 
{
    System.out.println("INSIDE SAMPLE");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream ("C:\\Automation\\Test\\inputData.xlsx");
    System.out.println("FILE");
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    System.out.println("WORKBOOK");
    wb.getSheet("MyDetails");
    System.out.println("SHEET");

    System.out.println(wb.getActiveSheetIndex());
}
```

}

**Below is the log when run from bat file:**

```
C:\Automation\Test>cd C:\Automation\Test

C:\Automation\Test>set ProjectPath=C:\Automation\Test

C:\Automation\Test>echo C:\Automation\Test
C:\Automation\Test

C:\Automation\Test>set classpath=C:\Automation\Test\bin;C:\Automation\Test\lib\*


C:\Automation\Test>echo C:\Automation\Test\bin;C:\Automation\Test\lib\*
C:\Automation\Test\bin;C:\Automation\Test\lib\*

C:\Automation\Test>java org.testng.TestNG C:\Automation\Test\testng.xml
...
... TestNG 6.8beta 20120825_1010 by C?dric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...

[TestRunner] Running the tests in 'Test' with parallel mode:false
[RunInfo] Adding method selector: org.testng.internal.XmlMethodSelector@14caa3f
priority: 10
[TestClass] Creating TestClass for [ClassImpl class=Master.Master]
[TestClass] Adding method Master.sample()[pri:0, instance:null] on TestClass cla
ss Master.Master
[XmlMethodSelector] Including method Master.sample()
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Automation\Test\testng.xml

[SuiteRunner] Created 1 TestRunners
[TestRunner] Running test Test on 1  classes,  included groups:[] excluded group
s:[]
===== Test class
Master.Master
    @Test Master.sample()[pri:0, instance:Master.Master@1150435]
======
[Invoker 6738746] Invoking Master.Master.sample
INSIDE SAMPLE
FILE
===== Invoked methods
    Master.sample()[pri:0, instance:Master.Master@1150435] 18154549
=====
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\Suite\Test.html
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\Suite\Test.xml
FAILED: sample
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook
        at Master.Master.sample(Master.java:79)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocat
ionHelper.java:80)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWork
er.java:127)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
        at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1338)
        at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1307)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFW
orkbook
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 24 more


===============================================
    Test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\old\Suite\toc.html
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\old\Suite\Test.properties
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\old\Suite\index.html
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\old\Suite\main.html
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\old\Suite\groups.html
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\old\Suite\methods.html
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\old\Suite\methods.html
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\old\Suite\methods.html
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\old\Suite\methods-alphabetical.html
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\old\Suite\methods-alphabetical.html
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\old\Suite\methods-alphabetical.html
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\old\Suite\classes.html
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\old\Suite\reporter-output.html
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\old\Suite\methods-not-run.html
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\old\Suite\testng.xml.html
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\old\index.html
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@1637f22: 53 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter@2d56bf: 3 ms
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\junitreports\TEST-Master.Master.xml
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@122cdd0: 4 ms
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\testng-failed.xml
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\Suite\testng-failed.xml
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 6 ms
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\index.html
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@1a4555e: 40 ms
Creating C:\Automation\Test\test-output\testng-results.xml
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@1b4f649: 6 ms

C:\Automation\Test>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your information. Please edit your question to include the script you used, and the error message displayed, if any.

Answer (score 0):

A data provider method is not supposed to throw exceptions. Manage them into your method and you'll understand what is wrong with your code.

I bet you have a classpath issue and `inputData.xlsx` is not available a the expected location when you run with you bat file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Below is my bat file:

Comment: cd C:\DCE\Automation
set ProjectPath=C:\DCE\Automation
set classpath=%ProjectPath%\bin;%ProjectPath%\lib\*
java org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\testng.xml
pause

Comment: I don't understand where I am doing wrong. If I run the testng.xml from Eclipse it works. Even the same bat file runs if I don't have reading excel steps. It is just the issue when opening excel from bat file.

Comment: Manage the exception and tell us what is the stacktrace

Comment: And set verbose=10 in your testng.xml

Comment: Please see my updates to the question. I simplified the script, but the issue still exists. I have provided the log

Comment: Apache poi is missing in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is resolved now. My poi files are sitting in project folder\lib\poi folder. I have moved them to project folder\lib. And it works.
Thanks @Julien Herr.